# Partial Isometries: Subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread was only Q&A.*

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider an operator:
$$J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K}):\quad P:=J^*J$$

By a previous thread:*
$$\mathcal{R}:=\mathcal{N}^\perp:\quad\mathcal{N}:=\mathcal{N}P=\mathcal{N}J$$

> Then one has:
>   $$\|J\varphi\|=\|\varphi\|\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{R})\iff P\varphi=\varphi\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{R})$$

How can I prove this?

**See the thread: [Kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1361113/79762)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: This answer is community wiki.*

Suppose partial isometry:
$$\|J\varphi\|=\|\varphi\|\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{R})$$

By polarization one gets:
$$\langle J\varphi,J\psi\rangle=\langle\varphi,\psi\rangle\quad(\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{R})$$

Note that one has:
$$\mathcal{N}=\overline{\mathcal{N}}:\quad\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{N}\oplus\mathcal{R}$$

So one obtains:
$$\langle P\varphi,\chi\rangle=\langle J\varphi,J\chi\rangle=\langle\varphi,\chi\rangle\quad(\chi\in\mathcal{R})$$
$$\langle P\varphi,\chi\rangle=\langle\varphi,P\chi\rangle=0=\langle\varphi,\chi\rangle\quad(\chi\in\mathcal{N})$$

Conversely one has:
$$\|J\varphi\|^2=\langle P\varphi,\varphi\rangle=\langle\varphi,\varphi\rangle=\|\varphi\|^2\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{R})$$

Concluding equivalence.