# Dense Operators: Kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is Q&A.*

**Problem**

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider an operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}A\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}$$

Then for the kernel:
$$\mathcal{N}A=\mathcal{N}(A^*A)$$

How can I prove this?

**Reference**

This is a lemma for: [Polar Decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/722478/79762), [Partial Isometries](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1122176/79762)

Comment: In case: Invoking the adjoint implicitely assumes dense domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{N}A\implies A\varphi=0\in\mathcal{D}A^*\implies\varphi\in\mathcal{N}(A^*A)$$

On the other hand:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{N}(A^*A)\implies\|A\varphi\|^2=\langle A^*A\varphi,\varphi\rangle=0\implies\varphi\in\mathcal{N}A$$

Concluding the assertion.

Comment: @user251257: Oh that was a typo. Thanks!! :) *(Corrected!)*

Answer (score 3):

We must assume ${\mathcal D}A$ is dense, otherwise $A^*$ is not well defined.

If $x \in {\mathcal D}A$ and $Ax = 0$ then of course $A^*A = 0$.

For the converse, note that  $y \in {\mathcal D} A^*$ with $A^* y = z$ iff for every $w \in {\mathcal D} A$, $\langle A w, y\rangle = \langle w, z\rangle$.  Now $x \in {\mathcal N} A^* A$ iff $x \in {\mathcal D} A$ and $Ax \in {\mathcal D} A^*$ with $A^*(Ax) = 0$, i.e. for every $w \in {\mathcal D}A$, 
$\langle Aw, Ax\rangle = \langle w, 0\rangle = 0$.  In particular this must be true for $w = x$, which says $Ax = 0$.

Comment: Yes that was implicitely by $A=A^{**}$. I reduced it now to $\overline{\mathcal{D}A}=\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: By the way you are really fast!!! :) (+1)